# Use $$ for BEGIN and $ for Variables in Scala SQL Block

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala

`IN` the code I have the following SQL block:

```
def updatetABLE(tableKey: String)(rowId: String, sendDate: String.....
    sql"""DO $$BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (select * from app_data where table_key = $tableKey...
```

After execution one of the `$` symbols before `BEGIN` gets removed and execution fails:

```
[SQL Execution Failed] DO $BEGIN IF EXISTS (select * from app_data where table_Key = 'E7F6872E2
```

How can I use `$$` for BEGIN and `$` for variables.

Comment: Which library is used?

Comment: Postgres' [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) isn't limited to `$$...$$` you could also use `$block$....$block$` - maybe that's easier to escape in Scala.

Comment: I am using "scalikejdbc", and I tried  $$$$ and $block$, both don't work.